# Melhor maneira de gerar uma li dinamicamente com javascript puro

Tags: javascript

Olá, tenho a seguinte estrutura

```
<li class="col-md-4">
<figure>
    <a class="list" href="#"><img alt="" src="image.png"></a>
    <div class="color">
        <small>teste</small>
        <span>post</span>
    </div>
 <figcaption>
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="progress"> <div style="width: 10%;" data-transitiongoal="10" role="pro-bar" class="pro-bar" aria-valuenow="20"><span>1080%</span></div> </div>
    </div>
        <div class="legeng">
            <div class="info">
                <h2><a href="">Titulo teste</a></h2>
                <p><img class="author" src="author.png">Nome</p>
            </div>
                <a href="" class="btn-bor readMore">Ver</a>
            </div>
 </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Gostaria de um bom exemplo para gerar ela várias vezes dinamicamente, usando javascript, pretendo receber um json e aplicar em todos os campos.

Comment: Pesquise pelo elemento `<template>`

Comment: não entendi como começar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você tiver um JSON em forma de `Array`, pode iterar sobre os itens e criar um `<li>` usando JavaScript:

```js
const data = [{
  name: 'Adalbeto',
  age: 23
}, {
  name: 'Bdalbeto',
  age: 45
}, {
  name: 'Cdalbeto',
  age: 37
}];

// Elemento em que os itens da lista serão `appendados`:
const list = document.getElementById('userlist');

/**
 * Aqui iteramos sobre cada elemento da lista usando o laço for...of.
 * Consulte as referências da resposta.
 */
for (const user of data) {
  const el = document.createElement('li');
  el.innerText = `${user.name} - ${user.age}`;

  list.appendChild(el);
}
```

```html
<h1>Usuários - Idade</h1>
<ul id="userlist"></ul>
```

#### Nota sobre compatibilidade de *browsers*:

O código JavaScript acima usa recursos novos do [EcmaScript 2015 (ou `ES6`)](http://es6-features.org/), como a declaração `const`, *template strings* e o laço `for...of`.

Com isso, caso você desejar fornecer um suporte à navegadores antigos, como o IE, deixarei uma tradução do código para `ES5`:

```js
var data = [{
  name: 'Adalbeto',
  age: 23
}, {
  name: 'Bdalbeto',
  age: 45
}, {
  name: 'Cdalbeto',
  age: 37
}];

var list = document.getElementById('userlist');

for (var index in data) {
  var user = data[index];
  var el = document.createElement('li');
  el.innerText = user.name + ' - ' + user.age;

  list.appendChild(el);
}
```

```html
<h1>Usuários - Idade</h1>
<ul id="userlist"></ul>
```

#### Referência:

- [Laço `for...of` (ES6)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of);
- [Laço `for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in);
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement);
- [`Node.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText);
- [`ParentNode.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append).

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar as [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings). Um exemplo, usando uma lista bem simples:

```js
const dadosJSON = [
    { nome: 'StackOverflow EN', url: 'https://stackoverflow.com/' },
    { nome: 'StackOverflow PT', url: 'https://pt.stackoverflow.com/' },
    { nome: 'User SOpt: 51214', url: 'https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/51214' }
]

var dadosHTML = ''

dadosJSON.forEach(dado => {
    dadosHTML += `<li><a href='${dado.url}'>${dado.nome}</a></li>`
})

document.getElementById('dados').innerHTML = dadosHTML
```

```html
<ul>
  <div id='dados'></div>
</ul>
```

Veja a compatibilidade com os navegadores no **[CanIUse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=template%20strings)**.